# Asking for password when cloning via ssh

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-clone

Im using a custom installation of gitlab.
Im in wsl2

Version of ssh :

```
ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

I created my ssh key , then
add it to gitlab

I also added the key with ssh-add

```
ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:XXX...XXX (RSA)
```

But I have an error when i want to clone a git repo via ssh

```
git clone git@XX.XX.XX.XX:user/repo_name.git
git@XX.XX.XX.XX's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

But when i do

```
ssh -T git@XX.XX.XX.XX
Welcome to GitLab, user
```

It don't ask me for a password.

Do someone have a solution ?
i already searched everywhere but found nothing

Comment: Did you start a ssh-agent and load the load the key using ssh-add?

Comment: @kometen i did .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad, it was an obvious problem that i didn't see.
For people who have the same prolem, the folowing solution will propably NOT be for you since is a special case.

Solution:
I was loged in with to my server with a **simple user**

and when i cloned i used **sudo**
so when conecting in ssh, the sytem searched for

```
root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

instead of

```
/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Where my ssh key actualy was,
So because it can't connect in ssh via the key,
the terminal show me a password to enter

The command that help me find this was

```
sudo GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone git@gitlab.example.com:my-group/my-project.git
```

*So avoid using sudo with git commands*

Comment: This helped me because I had given the key a custom name (when prompted) so SSH couldn't find it. Leave that option blank when using ssh-keygen.